# How to restore emulator UI to default settings?

Tags: android, android-emulator

There should be a bunch of buttons on dark gray background right of the phone screen. I started playing with the keyboard shortcuts available in that window and I must have done something to make the whole right-hand side of the emulator window disappear. How do I restore it?

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help: http://www.android.encke.net/android-emulator-tutorial.html - Ctrl-F11/F12 may get you back in order.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it, although Ctrl+F11/F12 do change the screen orientation. I tried every other combination listed on that page with no luck. I have not specified any Android Emulator Command Line Options either.

Comment: That's whacky.. The list of commands was taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html. I'm not sure if there are other hotkeys for the emulator.  I'll keep looking.